# Cannot update Realm 0.87.x -> 1.1.1

Tags: android, realm

My project uses a pre-gradle plugin Realm version - 0.87.4. I want to update Realm to the newest 1.1.1 version, but unlikely I get errors. To be more specific the project imports only io.realm.annotations package, but not the core of the library.

In my main build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

  ext.kotlin_version = "1.0.3"
  ext.realm_version = "1.1.1"
  repositories {
      jcenter()
      mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
      classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
      classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:$realm_version"
  }
}
```

In module's build.gradle I removed Realm dependencies and I replaced it with applying the realm-android plugin.

The library has been downloaded because realm-android-library exists in my_module/intermediates/exploded-arr/io.realm but the module doesn't import the library.

Comment: You'll need to clean and rebuild, and also add [`dexOptions { incremental false }`](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3196#issuecomment-233636226) to your build.gradle

Comment: It doesn't help. As was mentioned it the comment you linked, apply plugin: 'realm-android' is after apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

Comment: what errors did you get?

Comment: Still the same situation: cannot resolve Realm classes. I updated build.gradle, clean and refresh the project and only annotations package is available.

Comment: We changed something for kotlin, try with `ext.realm_version = "1.2.0-SNAPSHOT"`

Comment: Are you using multiple modules in your project?

Comment: Yes, i use multiple modules.

Comment: @beeender 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT changes nothing for me.

Comment: @kpob can you make a minimal project which can reproduce this issue and share it with us? to help@realm.io if you want to share it privately or anywhere we can reach. thanks

Comment: @beeender I will try to, but whenever I create a new project there's no issue at all. Maybe multiple modules are the reason. Anyway, if I'll be able to reproduce in a small project I'll let you know.

Comment: Although if you share the RealmObjects between your modules, then you would have had to make the realm objects available through a `@RealmModule` already, so this shouldn't be a problem either.